# How to get values through post method in a table in php and get the in the table replacing the previous table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having a table where I list all the products and have a filter in the table through which I'm filtering the products, now the problem I'm facing is I've fetched all the data in sql and I want to know how new table will be formed while filtering the parameters.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Begin: life time stats -->
                <div class="portlet light">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Products
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn default yellow-stripe dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-share"></i> Tools <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">
                                        Export to Excel </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">
                                        Export to CSV </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">
                                        Export to XML </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="divider">
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">
                                        Print Invoices </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div class="table-container">
                            <div class="table-actions-wrapper">
                                <span>
                                </span>
                                <select class="table-group-action-input form-control input-inline input-small input-sm">
                                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                                    <option value="publish">Publish</option>
                                    <option value="unpublished">Un-publish</option>
                                    <option value="delete">Delete</option>
                                </select>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm yellow table-group-action-submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable_products">
                            <thead>
                            <tr role="row" class="heading">
                                <th width="1%">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable">
                                </th>
                                <th width="10%">
                                     Product ID
                                </th>
                                <th width="15%">
                                     Product&nbsp;Name
                                </th>
                                <th width="15%">
                                     Category
                                </th>
                                <th width="10%">
                                     Price
                                </th>
                                <th width="10%">
                                     Stock
                                </th>
                                <th width="15%">
                                     SKU
                                </th>
                                <th width="10%">
                                     Status
                                </th>
                                <th width="10%">
                                     Product Image
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="filter">
                                <form method="post" action="productlist.php" id="searchform">
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" id="product_id" name="product_id">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="product_name">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="product_category" class="form-control form-filter input-sm">
                                                <option value="">Select...</option>
                                                <option value="1">Mens</option>
                                                <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Footwear</option>
                                                <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Clothing</option>
                                                <option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Accessories</option>
                                                <option value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion Outlet</option>
                                                <option value="6">Football Shirts</option>
                                                <option value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Premier League</option>
                                                <option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Football League</option>
                                                <option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Serie A</option>
                                                <option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bundesliga</option>
                                                <option value="11">Brands</option>
                                                <option value="12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adidas</option>
                                                <option value="13">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nike</option>
                                                <option value="14">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Airwalk</option>
                                                <option value="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;USA Pro</option>
                                                <option value="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kangol</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="margin-bottom-5">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="product_price_from" placeholder="From"/>
                                        </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="margin-bottom-5">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="product_quantity_from" placeholder="From"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group date date-picker margin-bottom-5" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" readonly name="product_created_from" placeholder="From">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="product_status" class="form-control form-filter input-sm">
                                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                                            <option value="published">Complete</option>
                                            <option value="published">Cancelled</option>
                                            <option value="published">Denied</option>
                                            <option value="published">Failed</option>
                                            <option value="notpublished">Refund</option>
                                            <option value="notpublished">Shipped</option>
                                            <option value="notpublished">Delivered</option>
                                            <option value="deleted">Reversed</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-actions">
                                                <div class="margin-bottom-5">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="validate">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-sm yellow filter-submit margin-bottom" name="search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <button class="btn btn-sm red filter-cancel" type ="reset"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Reset</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                </form>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                global $conn;
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM nits_product");

                                    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo '<tr role="row">';
                                            echo '<td width="1%"><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable"></td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Product ID">' . $record['product_id'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Product&nbsp;Name">' . $record['product_name'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Category">' . $record['product_categories'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Price">' . $record['product_price'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Stock">' . $record['product_stock'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="SKU">' . $record['product_sku'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Status">' . $record['product_status'] . '</td>';
                                            echo'<td data-th="Product Image">' . $record['product_images'] . '</td>';

                                        echo '</tr>';
                                }?>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End: life time stats -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to refresh page?

Comment: No. I want to bind the table with new data items based on the search query.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Content = function () {

    var initPickers = function () {
        //init date pickers
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            rtl: Metronic.isRTL(),
            autoclose: true
        });
  
  
    }

       
    var handleData = function() {
        var grid = new Datatable();

        grid.init({
            src: $("#datatable_content"),
            onSuccess: function (grid) {
                // execute some code after table records loaded
            },
            onError: function (grid) {
                // execute some code on network or other general error  
            },
            loadingMessage: 'Loading...',
            dataTable: { 
    "lengthMenu": [
                    [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150],
                    [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150] // change per page values here 
                ],
    
    
                "pageLength": 5, // default record count per page
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "?route=ajaxTableContent"//dataTable, // ajax source
                },
                "order": [
                    [0, "desc"]
                ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
    
            }
        });
  
  
  
   $('.filter-cancel').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
     var i =$(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
     var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
     grid.getDataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
            
   });
   $('.date-picker .form-control').on('change', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
     var i =$(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
     var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
    grid.getDataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
            })
   $('.form-filter').on( 'keyup', function () {   
    var i =$(this).attr('id'); 
    var v =$(this).val();  
    grid.getDataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
       //alert(v);           
   });
   grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.filter-submit', function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
      grid.getDataTable().ajax.reload(); // redrawing datatable
      grid.clearAjaxParams();        
   });
   $( ".select_id" ).on( "change", function( e, data ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    value = this.value ;
    var i =$(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
    var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
    grid.getDataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
    //alert(v);  
   });
 
         // handle group action submit button click
        grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.table-group-action-submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var action = $(".table-group-action-input", grid.getTableWrapper());
            if (action.val() != "" && grid.getSelectedRowsCount() > 0) {
                grid.setAjaxParam("customActionType", "group_action");
                grid.setAjaxParam("customActionName", action.val());
                grid.setAjaxParam("id", grid.getSelectedRows());
                grid.setAjaxParam("data_ids", grid.getSelectedRows());
     if (action.val() == "deleted") {
                  if (confirm("Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data ini ?") == false) {
                  return;
      }
              }
      var ids = [];
      $('.pilih_data').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        ids.push($(this).val());
       }
      });
      var ids_string = ids.toString();
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "?route=ajaxTableContent",//dataTable,
       data: {data_ids:ids_string,status: action.val()},
       success: function(result) {
        grid.getDataTable().ajax.reload(); // redrawing datatable
        grid.clearAjaxParams();
       },
       async:false
      });
      
    
            } else if (action.val() == "") {
                Metronic.alert({
                    type: 'danger',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    message: 'Please select an action',
                    container: grid.getTableWrapper(),
                    place: 'prepend'
                });
            } else if (grid.getSelectedRowsCount() === 0) {
                Metronic.alert({
                    type: 'danger',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    message: 'No record selected',
                    container: grid.getTableWrapper(),
                    place: 'prepend'
                });
            } 
        });
  
  
  grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.disable', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
     var actions  = jQuery(this).attr("id");
     var ids_string = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: dataTable,
       data: {data_ids:ids_string,status: actions},
       success: function(result) {
        grid.getDataTable().ajax.reload(); // redrawing datatable
        grid.clearAjaxParams();
        //alert(result);
       },
       async:false
      });
     
         });
  
  grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.enable', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
     var actions  = jQuery(this).attr("id");
     var ids_string = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: dataTable,
       data: {data_ids:ids_string,status: actions},
       success: function(result) {
        grid.getDataTable().ajax.reload(); // redrawing datatable
        grid.clearAjaxParams();
        //alert(result);
       },
       async:false
      });
         });
  
  grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.deleted', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
      var get_url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
     var actions  = jQuery(this).attr("id");
     var ids_string = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
                 if (confirm("Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data ini ?") == false) {
      return;
     }
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: dataTable,
       data: {data_ids:ids_string,status: actions},
       success: function(result) {
        //grid.getDataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
        grid.getDataTable().draw(); // redrawing datatable
        //grid.clearAjaxParams();
        //alert(result);
       },
       async:false
      });
        });
 
    
    }

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            handleData();
            initPickers();
            
        }

    };

}();
```

```html
<!-- Begin: life time stats -->
     <div class="portlet light">
      <div class="portlet-title">
       <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Pengaturan Content
       </div>
        <div class="actions btn-set">
                                
         <button type="button" name="back" class="btn default"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="?route=content&edit"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Tambah</a>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-body">
       <div class="table-container">
        <div class="table-actions-wrapper">
         <span>
                                    
         </span>
         <select class="table-group-action-input form-control input-inline input-small input-sm">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="publish">Publish</option>
          <option value="unpublished">Un-publish</option>
          <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
         </select>
         <button class="btn btn-sm yellow table-group-action-submit" data-href="?route=ajaxUpdateContent"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable_content">
        <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="heading">
         <th width="1%">
                                    
          <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable">
         </th>
         <th width="5%">
           ID
         </th>
         <th width="40%">
           Title
         </th>
         <th width="10%">
           Category
         </th>
         <th width="5%">
           Posted By
         </th>
         <th width="5%" class="center">
           Order
         </th>
         <th width="40%">
           Date
         </th>
         <th width="5%">
           Status
         </th>
         <th width="25%">
           Actions
         </th>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="filter">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td>
          <input type="text" id="0" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="id" placeholder="ID">
         </td>
         <td>
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="1" class="form-control form-filter input-sm t" name="title" placeholder="Title">
         </td>
         <td>
          <select  id="2" name="product_category" class="select_id form-control form-filter input-sm"> 
          <?php 
           $query_p = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories where parent=0");
            echo '<option value="0"> Kategori </option>';
            while ($tp = mysqli_fetch_array($query_p))
            {
        
            echo "<option value='$tp[cat_id]' >$tp[title]</option>";
            }
           ?>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td>
          <div class="margin-bottom-5">
           <input type="text" id="3" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="posted_by" placeholder="Posted By"/>
          </div>
          
         </td>
         <td>
          <div class="margin-bottom-5">
           <input type="text" id="4"  class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="order_id" placeholder="Order"/>
          </div>
          
         </td>
         <td>
          <div class="input-group date date-picker margin-bottom-5" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
           <input type="text" id="5"  class="t form-control form-filter input-sm" readonly name="date_created" placeholder="From">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-sm default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
           </span>
          </div>
          
         </td>
         <td>
          <select name="product_status" id="6" class="select_id form-control form-filter input-sm">
           <option value="">Select...</option>
           <option value="yes">Published</option>
           <option value="no">Not Published</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td>
          <div class="margin-bottom-5">
           <button class="btn btn-xs yellow filter-submit margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
          
          <button class="btn btn-xs red filter-cancel"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Reset</button>
                                        </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- End: life time stats -->
```

Comment: Please add some text which helps explain your answer, in addition to just code.

Answer (score 0):

ajaxTableContent.php
kode :

```html
<?php
/*
 * @author Jasriadi
 * @copyright © 2015 riauweb.com
 *
 */


if ($_POST['data_ids']){
  $data_ids = $_POST['data_ids'];
  $data_id_array = explode(",", $data_ids); 
  $status =$_POST['status'];
  if($status=='publish'){
   if(!empty($data_id_array)) {
    foreach($data_id_array as $id) {
     $query = "UPDATE content SET tool_show='yes' WHERE id='$id'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     echo $id;
    }
   }
  }else if($status=='unpublished'){
   if(!empty($data_id_array)) {
    foreach($data_id_array as $id) {
     $query = "UPDATE content SET tool_show='no' WHERE id='$id'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
   }
  }else if($status=='deleted'){
   if(!empty($data_id_array)) {
    foreach($data_id_array as $id) {
     
     
     $query = "DELETE FROM `content` WHERE id='$id'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
   }
  }
  
}


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
 0 => 'id', 
 1 => 'title',
 2 => 'cat_id',
 3 => 'posted_by',
 4 => 'tool_no',
 5 => 'date_created',
 6 => 'tool_show'
);



// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT id";
$sql.=" FROM content";
$query=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `description`, `cat_id`, `tool_url`, `uid`, `icon_name`, `meta_title`, `meta_des`, `meta_tags`, `about_tool`, `tool_show`, `tool_no`, `tool_login`, `posted_by`, date_created, `headline` ";
$sql.=" FROM content WHERE 1=1";


if( !empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  id LIKE '%$q%' ";    
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  title LIKE '%$q%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  cat_id LIKE '%$q%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  posted_by LIKE '%$q%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  tool_no LIKE '%$q%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][5]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][5]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][5]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  date_created LIKE '%$q%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][6]['search']['value']) ){
 $q = isset($requestData['columns'][6]['search']['value']) ? trim($requestData['columns'][6]['search']['value']) :"";
 $q = searchMe($q);
 $sql.=" AND  tool_show LIKE '%$q%' ";
}

$query=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains column index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */ 
$query=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees1");
 

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 
 $toolActive = filter_var($row["tool_show"], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
         if($toolActive){
            $toolActive = "<span class='label label-sm label-success'>Active</span>";
            $toolActiveBut = '<a href="?route=content&id='.$row["id"].'&edit" class="btn btn-xs blue"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a><a class="btn btn-xs yellow btn-danger btn-sm disable" href="?route=ajaxUpdateContent&data_ids='.$row["id"].'&disable" id="unpublished" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">Disable</a>';
           }else{
             $toolActive = "<span class='label label-sm label-info'>Not Active</span>"; 
             $toolActiveBut = '<a href="?route=content&id='.$row["id"].'&edit" class="btn btn-xs blue"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a><a class="btn btn-xs green btn-success enable" href="?route=ajaxUpdateContent&data_ids='.$row["id"].'&enable" id="publish" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">Enable</a>';
          }
 $category = GETCONTENT::getCategories($con, $row["cat_id"]);
 $nestedData[] = '<input type="checkbox" class="pilih_data" name="id[]" value="'.$row["id"].'">';
 $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["title"];
 $nestedData[] = $category["title"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["posted_by"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["tool_no"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["date_created"];
 $nestedData[] = ''.$toolActive.'';
 $nestedData[] = '
   '.$toolActiveBut.'<a href="../news/'.$row["tool_url"].'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-xs blue"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View</a>
  ';
 
 $data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
   "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw Data
   "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
   "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // Pencarian Data
   "data"            => $data   // total data array
   );
if (isset($_REQUEST["customActionType"]) && $_REQUEST["customActionType"] == "group_action") {
$statusAction = $_REQUEST['customActionName'];//Type Publish
$json_data["customActionStatus"] = "OK"; // pass custom message(useful for getting status of group actions)
$json_data["customActionMessage"] = ' Data successfully has been '.$statusAction.'  completed. Well ok!';
 
  }
echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```